# ERROR: value too long for type character varying

Tags: postgresql, informix

tengo la siguiente consulta en informix y se creo el archivo csv para poder migrar la informacion a postgresql el problema es que cuando importo la informacion al postgresql me manda el siguiente error:

```
"ERROR: value too long for type character varying"
```

El campo en la base de datos de informix aparece como `char(200,10)` y lo estoy migrando a postgresql y esta como `varchar(250)`, ¿Cuál sera la problemática?

Comment: Y la consulta? Pásate por [ask] y haz el [tour] luego podrás [edit] tu pregunta para mejorarla.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo del archivo `CSV` que estas intentando cargar y la estructura de la tabla en PostgreSQL?

Comment: usa TEXT. no vale la pena la micro-optimización en ese nivel. Una vez con tu data importada podrás explorar cómo optimizar